# Should I be using multiple SQL queries or multiple loops in my client code?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

I'm building a small internal phone number extension list.

In the database I have two tables, a `people` table, and a `numbers` table. The relationship is a `one-to-many` respectively.

I want to display the results in a single HTML table with one person per row but if they have multiple numbers it shows those in a single column with a rowspan on the person row to compensate.

Now, to get the results from the database to work with, I can either do:

```
(pseudocode)

SELECT id, name
FROM people

foreach result as row {
  SELECT number
  FROM numbers
  WHERE numbers.person_id = row['id']
}
```

This would mean that I'm doing one query to get all users, but then if I have 100 users, I'm performing 100 additional queries to get the numbers for each user.

Instead I could do it like this:

```
(pseudocode)

SELECT number, person_id
FROM numbers

SELECT id, name
FROM people

foreach people as person {
  echo name
  foreach numbers as number {
    if (number.id = person.id) {
      echo number
    }
  }
}
```

So, essentially it is doing the exact same thing except instead I do two queries to get all the results into arrays and then loop through the arrays to format my tables.

**Which method should I be using or is there a better way to do this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common way is to do a regular JOIN:

```
SELECT id, name, number
FROM people, numbers
WHERE people.id = numbers.person_id;
```

You can either add an `ORDER BY` to get the numbers in order, or you could create an array with a single pass over the resultset, and then loop through that array.

You can also consider a [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to concatenate all the numbers for the same person:

```
SELECT id, name, GROUP_CONCAT(number SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM people, numbers
WHERE people.id = numbers.person_id
GROUP BY people.id;
```

---

Since you are even asking this question: I cannot stress the fact that you *should* pick up an introductory book on database design. It helped me wonders to learn the theories behind relational databases.

Comment: I believe your query is what the asker is already doing in his nested loop example, however, your `GROUP_CONCAT` idea is a great one that I will probably end using.

Comment: morrty still uses two queries in the second example. Not too nice to reimplement joining imo.

Comment: @EmilVikström Yep, sorry.  Did not see the two queries at the top and I assumed he was joining!  This reinforces my vote for your answer haha.

Comment: Ah, actually, I don't think this will work on second thought, unless the query can be modified. Since I was trying to keep the OP simple, I didn't mention that the `numbers` table has another column with `type` (mobile, work, extension, etc). Can the current query be modified to allow this?

Comment: What you do when joining to tables is that you basically create a combination of every row in one table with every row in the second. You can just add whatever columns you want in the column-list. Not sure about the GROUP_CONCAT, though.

Comment: @EmilVikström `SELECT locations.name AS location, contacts.name, contacts.title,
 GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(' {', types.name, '} ', numbers.number) SEPARATOR ' | ') AS numbers
FROM contacts
 INNER JOIN numbers ON contacts.id = numbers.contacts_id
 INNER JOIN locations ON contacts.locations_id = locations.id
 INNER JOIN TYPES ON numbers.types_id = types.id
GROUP BY contacts.id` - This seems to work.

Comment: @RyanMortier. Are you sure there will always be a TYPES record for every phone number? If not then you should use a LEFT OUTER JOIN to the TYPES table so that you will ensure getting a phone number even if its type is not specified.

Comment: @Michael.M in this case, yes. However I'll take your post into consideration if we change this application in the future.

Answer (score 4):

You *probably* want to execute just *one* query.  Something like

```
select people.id, people.name, group_concat(numbers.number)
from people 
inner join numbers on numbers.id = people.id
group by people.id, people.name
order by people.name
```

Then you can loop over the result set with simple php code.

Comment: I think this might work, however, it throws all the numbers into a single field separated by a comma. Is there another separator it can use other than comma?

Comment: Yes. [GROUP_CONCAT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). You can even use HTML markup as the separator: `group_concat(numbers.number separator '<br/>')`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, and you may have to time it to find out.  Doing multiple queries is a lot of network turns if your database is on a different computer than your web server, so often this takes longer.  However, if your database server is on the same computer as your web server, this might not be an issue.

Also consider the time it will take to look up the number in the array.  As an array you are doing a linear order O(N) search.  If you can put it in a hash, the lookup will be much faster, and the two query approach may be faster, but not if you spend a lot of time looking up the answer in your array.

Using a join to get it into one query, may be fastest, as the numbers will be associated with the people, depending on your container structure you are storing the data into to be accessed in your foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use a stored procedure or function to retrive the data, don't wite the sql in your programm

Answer (score 0):

You should do neither. You can do *one* query (join) over the tables:

```
select name, number
from people p, numbers n
where p.id = n.person_id
order by name, number;
```

and then just *one* loop:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(...);
$query = 'select name, number from people p, numbers n where p.id = n.person_id order by name, number';

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    $person = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        if ($row['name'] !== $person) {
            $person = $row['name'];
            echo $person;
        }

        echo $row['number'];
    }
}
```